# In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-query-language

Tried all the solutions did not work

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("19_HAo-q9PuVtMxBWhXDQ_ftmikKzU-eNlSFxl3KwUvE","August19 Tracker!A2:O");IMPORTRANGE("1O_GIuel6WYpYx7cqdhAdLLzHF_wctjJ3aWmAR3I0oIo","August 19!A2:O")},"Select * where (Col1<> '' and Col6<> '')")
```

Comment: Hi Suhas, Would you please edit your question and explain more?

Comment: Hi,
There is no data even when the query is right, the error iam finding is this:
"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"